# wordpress subfolder redirection + non-www to www redirection

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have my .htaccess set up so that my wordpress works on the main domain instead of the installation folder.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ folder/index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

And that works mostly fine, but when you write `website.com` without the `www.` it just doesn't show. I looked for a solution and thought I had found it, but that started giving me a "too many redirections" error and didn't show anything.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
#
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ folder/index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

So now I'm back to it just not showing without the `www.` :c